# Cannot connect to react native debugger

Tags: react-native, debugging, remote-debugging, react-native-debugger

When I open my app in Expo and press "Open JS Debugger", a separate window opens and react native debugger still waiting for connect. When I close this window, JS Debugger automatically turns off. After that I do these steps again and it opens in a separate window again.
[Here is this separate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkIre.jpg)

Interestingly, that in another project it opens in react native debugger. I doubt, that the problem is because i use TS instead of JS.

I have been trying to fix this problem by searching in google but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to your app.json file add this to your expo objects "jsEngine": "jsc",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: debugger option gone after i added jsEngine to jsc. any idea?

Comment: I get the warning `No compatible apps connected. JavaScript Debugging can only be used with the Hermes engine.` in my expo console. Also, this article suggests, that only hermes, but not jsc should work for JS debugging: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-hermes/#troubleshooting